# cakePHP: how to get iterator

Tags: cakephp, foreach

Im using something similar to this code:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <div><?php echo $item['Item']['content']; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And i'd like to know which element is every item, because i want to add class "last-in-row" for every fourth item in row. How to make something like this code?

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i <= $items.count; $i++) {
    echo "<div ";
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo " class=\"last-in-row\""; }
    echo ">$items[$i]</div>";
}; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it but the following should work.

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $class = ($i % 4 == 0) ? '' : 'class="last-in-row"';
  echo "<div $class>{$item['Item']['content']}</div>";
  $i++;
} 
?>
```

p.s. I hope you are [sanitizing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html#Sanitize%3a%3ahtml) $item['Item']['content'].

Comment: Won't this mark the first row as "last-in-row"? Surely $i needs to start from 1.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja good point... as I said, I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: You don't sanitize! You escape - using `echo h($value);`

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do could be done with css3. This will mean you do not need to add a class which is fat better as later on you might want 3 or 5 in a row.

```
div:nth-child(4n+4) {
    ....
    clear: both;
    ....
}
```

The CakePHP option without css3

```
foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
    echo $this->Html->tag('div', $item['Item']['content'], array(
        'class' => ($i + 1) % 4 === 0 ? 'last' : null
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You nearly had it in your second example, just change `$items.count` to the value of `count($items)`

```
$itemsCount = count($items);
for ($i=1; $i <= $itemsCount ; $i++) {
    echo "<div ";
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo " class=\"last-in-row\""; }
    echo ">{$items[$i]}</div>";
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the index of $items always increments by 1. Using a foreach loop with a counter variable works better as it makes no such assumption.

Comment: True, I was just fixing OPs attempt.